# Express, Angular, Universal and how to get the base url using injection

Tags: angular-universal

How do I get the port number from express into Angular Universal, but still make the front end usable. (Angular 13)

So the basics of the setup. I have Angular Universal (the heros tutorial) loaded.

In the server.ts file I add this to my renderer:
`res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }, { provide: BASE_URL, useValue: req.get('host') }] });`

The base url is defined in a new file:
`export const BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('BaseUrl');`

Next, I need to import that base url into a component/service constructor:
`@Inject(BASE_URL) private baseUrl: string`

and then console log that out in my onInit or constructor...
`console.log(this.baseUrl);`

Run the whole thing and it gives me the number in the console where I am running my website.

Now, the front end of course crashes. (We don't know where to get the base url injection from, since we did not declare that as a provider to our app. Lets do that:
`providers: [{ provide: BASE_URL, useValue: "test"}]`

ok, Now... we run it, and suddenly we get "test" in our console for express, and the app works.

Is there a way to do both? Get the port from express and not bomb on the front end.

I want to get the base url when running SSR, but get an empty string when running in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:
Do not use a provider in app.module.ts and use the optional keyword when injecting it into your constructor/service

```
@Optional() @Inject(BASE_URL) private baseUrl: string
```